# Como pasar variales por url en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

como puedo pasar variable por url en wordpress?

echo "Enviar nota";

y recojo esos datos con $_GET['nombre'];
Pero no me funciona

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Las variables `GET` se pasan directamente en la URL.

Las variables se separan con el simbolo `&` y estas se separan de la URL con el simbolo `?`.

El formato de las variables es `clave=valor`.

Si tomamos en consideración lo anterior y nuestra url es `http://google.cl` y queremos pasar la variable `nombre` nuestra URL se vería así:

```
http://google.cl?nombre=cesar
```

En caso que necesitemos pasar más variables como el apellido, utilizamos el concatenador mencionado anteriormente.

```
http://google.cl?nombre=cesar&apellido=mora
```

Para validar que una variable exista, puedes utilizar la función `isset()`

```
if(isset($_GET['nombre'])){
    //Haz algo
}
```

Puedes leer más de $_GET en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php) de php